# In app-purchased android

Tags: in-app-purchase, google-play-services, google-play-developer-api, android-inapp-purchase

I am working on IAP since last two days but did not find the exact solution for that

1. If user is login with multiple gmail account in play store, at that time, why does it automatically pick primary id?
2. I've already purchased a product with my gmail(abc@gmail.com) on my device. Now i changed the device and check programmatically this product is purchased for me or not using same id(abc@gmail.com) then it returns null values of inventory details while i'm using labHelper.class.

Is this Google Play services  Bug or I'm going wrong?

Comment: Not sure what it is that you are asking for here. If you are seeing an in issue, let us know the steps to recreate?

Comment: @StephenMurby if user is login with multiple gmail account in play store, at that time why it automatically pick primary id(during app purchased)?????  i hope you understand the question well